# SQL how to get average of created column

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have this Query

```
SELECT stock,
      ROUND(AVG(dividend / price) *100,3) AS yield 
FROM stock
GROUP BY stock
```

Im trying to take the average of yield and display all stocks that have a yield that is higher than the average of yield.

I tried this

```
SELECT stock,
          ROUND(AVG(dividend / price) *100,3) AS yield 
    FROM stock
    WHERE yield > AVG(yield)
    GROUP BY stock
```

but I get an error and it doesnt work.

Answer (score 1):

Use a subquery and `join` is probably the simplest:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM (SELECT stock,
             ROUND(AVG(dividend / price) * 100, 3) AS yield 
      FROM stock
      GROUP BY stock
     ) as s INNER JOIN
     (SELECT AVG(yield) as avg_yield
      FROM (SELECT stock,
                   ROUND(AVG(dividend / price) * 100, 3) AS yield 
            FROM stock
            GROUP BY stock
           ) as s
     ) as ss
     ON s.yield >= s.avg_yield;
```